# STRAPI DEPLOY - error 404 media library files - OVH

Tags: deployment, http-status-code-404, strapi, ovh

I'm seeking your help. I deployed Strapi on an OVH hosting, as usual (maybe it's the 10th time). I'm facing an issue with the media library. The links to the images are all broken. I'm getting 404 errors, and when I try to upload a new image, the process goes through, but in the end, I still get a broken image. It's worth noting that I deployed the same application on my hosting, which is identical to the client's, and it's working correctly there. Thank you in advance for your assistance. Have a great day!

Likewise, as I mentioned, I tried deploying the same code on two identical OVH servers, just like the client's, and everything works. I also checked the FTP access rights, and they are also fine. The OVH support seems to be unavailable; I haven't received any response from them.